# При наведении на элемент навигации съезжают пункты списка

Tags: html, css, css3

Есть маркированный список. При наведении шрифт становится `font-weight:bold`, при этом подвигаются соседние пункты списка. Как это можно исправить?

```
<nav>
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="navbar">
        <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">about us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">expertise</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">programs</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">our impact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">symposia</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">voluntreer</a></li>
    </ul>
    <form class="search-form">
        <input type="search">
    </form>
    <button class="search-btn"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
    </div>
</nav>
```

и sass:

```
ul.navbar
  display: flex
  list-style: none

  li
    margin-right: 30px

        a
          color: #fefefe
          text-align: center
          text-transform: uppercase
          text-decoration: none
          font-size: 13px

          &:hover,
          &:active
            font-weight: 500
```

Comment: Приведите ваш код

Comment: При соответствующем описании вопроса, ответ будет - как-нибудь

Comment: выложил код, если это поможет

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть, например, такой хук с применением псевдоэлемента:

```css
ul.navbar {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  margin-right: 30px;
}

a {
  display: block;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 13px;
}
a:after {
  display: block;
  content: attr(title);
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  visibility: hidden;
}
a:hover, a:active {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="navbar">
      <li><a href="#" title="home">home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" title="about us">about us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" title="expertise">expertise</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" title="programs">programs</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" title="our impact">our impact</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" title="symposia">symposia</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" title="voluntreer">voluntreer</a></li>
    </ul>
    <form class="search-form">
      <input type="search">
    </form>
    <button class="search-btn"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
  </div>
</nav>
```

[CodePen с SASS кодом](https://codepen.io/semenchenko/pen/VyKrLv?editors=1100)

Comment: весь шкаф забит шляпками и "нечего надеть!"  :)  (+) плюс не за это, а за ответ

Comment: @Alexandr_T, ах это женское настроение, то оно есть, то его нет. Пропало и сняла все шляпки))))

Answer (score 0):

Если вы имеете ввиду последовательность блоков по горизонтали, то один из вариантов это сделать элементы фиксированной ширины. Ширину задавать вручную или вычислить с помощью javascript. При этом ширина должна браться с запасом на расширение при изменении на жирный шрифт.